# Print as many images in a row as fit the page

Tags: context, svg, border

I have a svg image for a tile in a board game. I want to print this 3 times so that I can print the page and cut out the tiles for my game. However, I cannot figure out how to print as many tiles next to each other as fit the page: in variant A I get three tiles in a row, but the thrird overlaps the page border and gets cut off. In variant B each tile gets on a new line, leaving too much room on the page empty.

My context code:

```
\setuppapersize[letter, singlesided]

% Extends beyond right edge
\define\tileBlueA{\dontleavehmode\externalfigure[blue.svg][frame=on]}
% Each image on its own line
\define\tileBlueB{\externalfigure[blue.svg][frame=on]}

\startdocument

Variant A:

\tileBlueA\tileBlueA\tileBlueA

Variant B:

\tileBlueB\tileBlueB\tileBlueB

\stopdocument
```

The svg image:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="70mm"
   height="60.812588mm"
   viewBox="0 0 70 60.812588"
   version="1.1">
  <g transform="translate(-7.9019751,26.241753)">
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.53316474;stroke-miter
       d="m -116.41665,214.60119 -32.43408,15.26465 -61.61849,28.19872 -29.43661,-20.45642 -55.23006,-39.26382 2.99747
       transform="matrix(0.2740972,-0.192523,0.192523,0.2740972,68.200203,-77.001058)" />
    <circle
       style="opacity:1;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.2;stroke-miterlimit:4
       cx="42.901974"
       cy="4.1645398"
       r="14.552083"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

How can I print as many tiles as fit in a row (here 2)?

(I do not want to scale them, and would prefer to not insert line breaks manually, as I'll have a lot of tiles.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SVG doesn't work in my computer nor my PDF viewers once the SVG is embedded in the main file and I don't know who to blame. So I chose some examples from Wikimedia Commons. Due to strange rounding issues on the TeX side, I've made all calculations on the Lua side, what may be wrong or ugly, but useful. It will possibly crash when your picture is too wide...

```
\showframe
\setuppapersize[letter, singlesided]
\def\howmanyinarow#1#2%
{\setbox\scratchbox\hbox{#2}
%In order to avoid rounding annoyances
\scratchcounter
    \luaexpr
    {math.floor(\the\numexpr\textwidth\relax/\the\numexpr\wd\scratchbox\relax)}
    \relax
\dorecurse{#1}
    {\quitvmode{#2}%
    \doifelse
    {\luaexpr{\recurselevel\letterpercent\the\scratchcounter}}{0}
    {\par}{}% <- Don't remove me!
    }}
\starttext
%https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Stylized_uwu_emoticon.svg
\howmanyinarow{10}{\externalfigure[Stylized_uwu_emoticon.svg][frame=on]}
%https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Caoandanielinbluegood.svg
\howmanyinarow{100}{\externalfigure[Caoandanielinbluegood.svg][frame=on]}
\stoptext
```

[image]

**Edit:** If you only want *one* (1) row, you could just use `\leaders` instead

```
\showframe
%Shamelessly stolen from TeX for the Impatient
%Easier
\def\howmanyinarow#1{\line{\leaders\hbox{#1}\hfil}}
\starttext
%https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Caoandanielinbluegood.svg
\howmanyinarow{\externalfigure[Stylized_uwu_emoticon.svg][frame=on]}

%https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Caoandanielinbluegood.svg
\howmanyinarow{\externalfigure[Caoandanielinbluegood.svg][frame=on]}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks... I was hoping to not have to calculate things manually.

Comment: @Robert I split command examples so it becomes clear that there are two commands, in case it helps. :)